# C# Form Draws Slowly

Tags: c#, forms

I made an application on Visual Studio 2012 and im trying to speed up the draw times of the forms.

I have a main form and inside of it i have a container in which depending on the selection of a tool strip, the new form will show inside of it. It works like a charm, but the issue is, it takes a lot of time to draw, no matter how good the computer is (tried on different computers), and the issue seems to be the background.

I have set a background image for the main form, for the container inside that form, and for all the forms in my project, so when they show up, the background image isnt chopped and it continues the image. But, if instead of using a background for picture and i leave the back in white, for all, the main form, container, and forms, it works like a charm.

I've read around the internet about setting the double buffer inside the form and stuff to true, but it didnt do anything, it takes the same ammount of time.

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: WinForms does not work well with background images, especially if they're high-resolution. That said, I can't stand programs with background images. Consider using a solid colour instead.

Comment: Hey, if you want a custom layout, just take a look at WPF. It uses Direct X (instead of GDI) to render the window which makes it extremely fast.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the tip, but using a solid colour is not an option.

Comment: @Snicker Thanks a lot, but im using VS 2012 and from what i've read, WPF is present on VS 2015

Comment: @Lobialkon WPF was first introduced in Visual Studio 2008, you can use it in 2012. Also why are you using 2012, you can use 2015 [for free](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh, thanks, i just googled WPF and the first thing i see is that is present on VS 2015, still dont know what that is or how to use it so im going to do a little research first

Comment: @Lobialkon WPF you can say is a more advanced form than winforms. It is something in between ASP.NET and winforms in terms of how you design things and what you can do is how one can define it I think. In essence it is mightier than winforms and you can do more but on the other hand it is more complicated than winforms.  and Scott is correct that it is already available in VS 2012.  If you want you can think of it as the big brother of winforms who was once said that it is going to replace winforms (which it didn't  historywise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can squeeze a *little* more speed out of it by drawing the background manually.  This helps because it allows you to disable the underlying background color, which just wastes time because it gets overwritten with the image anyway.

```
// Reference to manually-loaded background image
Image _bmp;

// In your constructor, set these styles to ensure that the background
// is not going to be automatically erased and filled with a color
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    SetStyle(
        ControlStyles.Opaque |
        ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | 
        ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

    // Load background image
    _bmp = Image.FromFile("c:\\path\\to\\background.bmp");
}

// Override OnPaint to draw the background
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    var g = e.Graphics;
    var srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, _bmp.Width, _bmp.Height);
    int startY = Math.Max(0, (e.ClipRectangle.Top / _bmp.Height) * _bmp.Height);
    int startX = Math.Max(0, (e.ClipRectangle.Left / _bmp.Width) * _bmp.Width);
    for (int y = startY; y < e.ClipRectangle.Bottom; y+= _bmp.Height)
        for (int x = startX; x < e.ClipRectangle.Right; x += _bmp.Width)
        {
            var destRect = new Rectangle(x, y, _bmp.Width, _bmp.Height);
            g.DrawImage(_bmp, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Comment: Although it draws quite a lot faster, it changed how the background looks, here, ill leave two images of it for you to see. Original: http://imgur.com/fWYvrpH  ; Changed: http://imgur.com/Rg4ddPG

Comment: Ok, so it's drawing the image using a different scale because the DPI of the bitmap does not match your desktop DPI.  Also, the original behavior (using the BackgroundImage property) is to repeat the bitmap as needed to fill the whole space.  I have modified my answer to account for both of these issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not its loading a lot faster than it used to! Ill do some research on some of the things you mentioned in your code as im not familliar with them!